# Which Part of the RMI Server be implemented with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi, runnable

I've just started RMI programming recently and had complete most of the parts for the assignment requirements. But there was this question in my head where one of the requirements is supporting multiple threads. Basically in which part should the multi thread be implemented?
Should I make the Server class Runnable or make the objects that are being created in the Server class Runnable?
Here's the code of my Server class:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String portNum = "4444";
    try {
        Account_Server_Controller accountController = new Account_Server_Controller();

        BookCategory_Server_Controller categoryController = new BookCategory_Server_Controller();

        Book_Server_Controller bookController = new Book_Server_Controller();

        BookActivity_Server_Controller bookActivityController = new BookActivity_Server_Controller();

        startRegistry(Integer.parseInt(portNum));
        Naming.rebind(ServerLocater.getAccountRegistryURL(), accountController);
        Naming.rebind(ServerLocater.getBookRegistryURL(), bookController);
        Naming.rebind(ServerLocater.getCategoryRegistryURL(), categoryController);
        Naming.rebind(ServerLocater.getBookActivityRegistryURL(), bookActivityController);
        System.out.println("Server is Ready.");
    } catch (NumberFormatException | MalformedURLException | RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in Server.main: " + e);
    }
}

private static void startRegistry(int rmiPortNum) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(rmiPortNum);
        registry.list();
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        System.out.println("RMI registry is not located at port " + rmiPortNum);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiPortNum);
        System.out.println("RMI registry created at port " + rmiPortNum);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: RMI Servers are multi-threaded (one thread per client) by default AFAIK. I suspect you don't need to do anything here, only in your implementation.

Comment: So the object such as Account_Server_Controller in my case should be modify to work with multi-thread? All the contollers shown in my Server class are being implemented with different interfaces.

Comment: You need to store the result of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` in a static variable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey One thread per connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You don't have to start any threads or implement any `Runnables`.

You just have to make sure that your remote method implementations are thread-safe.

Comment: Example like each object only handles one table? I’m using txt file to store my data btw.

Comment: I don't understand the question, but, as I already stated, thread-safety of remote method implementations is entirely up to you.